# group by column 1 and sum the unique occurences of column 2

Tags: bash, group-by, count

I have a 2 column file of identifiers: id1 and id2. It has total 1643 rows. Each row is a unique combination of id1 and id2

Here are the first rows:

```
id1,id2
AAACCCACAGACTGCC,CTGGCTTTCT
AAACCCATCCACCCTA,ATGACGACTN
AAACGAAAGTACAACA,CGCACAACGN
AAACGAAGTTGGAGAC,TATATTACAC
AAACGAAGTTGGAGAC,TTAGTATGTN
AAACGAAGTTGGAGAC,TTTCCTTATC
AAACGAATCCTTCACG,ATCAACATCN
AAACGCTTCAGCCCAG,TACGCCACAN
AAAGAACCAAGTCATC,CTTCTTAGTT
AAAGAACCAAGTCATC,GCTTGCTCGT
```

I have 1433 unique id1 and 1632 unique id2. I want to group by the id1 and count how many unique id2 I have for each id1. I want an output file with the unique id1 in the first column and the number of the unique corresponding id2 in the second column. For the above toy input, the intended output is

```
id1,n
AAACCCACAGACTGCC,1
AAACCCATCCACCCTA,1
AAACGAAAGTACAACA,1
AAACGAAGTTGGAGAC,3
AAACGAATCCTTCACG,1
AAACGCTTCAGCCCAG,1
AAAGAACCAAGTCATC,2
```

I cannot find a way to do that in bash. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!
Eleni

Comment: Kindly do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS and also post your efforts in form of code in your question(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I made the changes, thanks for the suggestions. I hope my question is more understandable now.

Comment: `sed '1d' file | cut -d ',' -f 1 | uniq -c`?

Comment: This also worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example data stored in the file id1id2 and using awk:

```
awk -F, '{ id[$1][$2]="" } END { for (i in id) { count=0;printf "%s","\n"i"\t";for (j in id[i]) { count++ } printf "%s",count } printf "%s","\n" }' id1id2 > id1id2count
```

Use , as a field separator and then create a multi-dimentional array using id1 and id2 as the indices. Then loop through the array counting the number of unique id2s and each id1, printing them as we go along. Redirect the output to another file, id1id2count

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#,.*##' file.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 "," $1 }'
```

1. Delete komma and id2 in all lines
2. sort lines in order to make same id1 adjacent
3. count occurrences of all id1
4. format output